# Puzzled by disappearance of questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions

There is a [relatively new user,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/325411/martinusa?tab=topactivity) who has asked a number of questions to which I have commented. The questions have disappeared, and they are not on his/her activity profile.

The reason I have noticed this is because I became interested in the subject and had some links in comments to the disappeared questions which I can no longer find.

How does this happen? The user deletes the questions and then they disappear from the profile? As all the questions are about the same subject, it defeats the purpose of the site, as there can be no buildup of knowledge if the user deletes questions he/she is no longer interested in.

Comment: Slightly related: It became [easier to locate deleted posts in early January 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/375078#375078). Though it probably doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 8):

The questions you remember are simply deleted ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/689245/50583), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688961/50583), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688794/50583), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688789/50583)) - authors can delete their questions that have no positively-scoring answer. If there is a positively-scored answer they cannot delete their question, so knowledge that at least one user found valuable *cannot* just vanish by people deleting their old questions.

Comment: Thanks, I got the links I was looking for. Is there a  way to find deleted questions without asking you?

Comment: As a high-rep user, you can [search for your own deleted posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching). For all users, at the bottom of the “answers” and “questions” sections of your profile page, there are links which show some of your deleted posts.

Comment: @rob it shows all of them now.  you can use this link to point people there. https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current

Comment: @annav You can also just go to your browser history and get to the posts from there. That is usually what I do.

Comment: @rob one disappeared question ( the jupiter one) https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/689528/how-to-get-an-approximate-estimation-of-the-flux-of-trapped-1-gev-protons-aroundhas arrived by a new user

Comment: @BioPhysicist thanks. I would not be asking the above if I knew this.